# Blazor Server with Web Api

Tags: api, jwt, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-authorization

I have a project structure which includes a Blazor server project and an api project.

Every things works fine, but I'm confused about how to handle security. I use JWT in the  api, and in Blazor server I use scaffold identity.

How can I integrate the security between the two project?

Should I use JWT for both and override authentication state provider?

https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/contribute/article_images/1220200705121732/blazor-application-architecture.png

#**edit**

I don't want to use the Identityserver4 as the version 5(duendesoftware) will be paid , the support for identityserver4 will be terminate at Nov 2022 with the end of .net core 3 support, So that I need any replacement that's free
or a cimple way to do the authentication between the two layer
Thanks

Comment: Welcome...Please, make sure you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: maybe this wil help: https://community.auth0.com/t/web-api-blazor-server-side-w-jwt-and-cookie-auth/54066/5